# Does it matter if I open one or two doors?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does air pressure equalize more quickly if the doors are open?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/85514/does-air-pressure-equalize-more-quickly-if-the-doors-are-open)

If two rooms, or a room and space, are connected by two doors, does it make a difference whether I open one or both of the doors?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[Yes. When I did my analysis of oxygen flow between rooms, I had a situation where opening a second door caused a change in the steady-state of oxygen.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/85815/2640)

Oxygen equalizes at a rate proportional to the difference between two rooms, at each door. So with two doors open it will equalize faster.